# Maven Error Pom.xml - frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, aem, pom.xml

I am trying to build the project but getting error :

```
[ERROR] Plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.10.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:jar:1.10.0: Could not transfer artifact com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:pom:1.10.0 from/to adobe-public-releases (https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Transfer failed for https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/1.10.0/frontend-maven-plugin-1.10.0.pom: Connect to repo.adobe.com:443 [repo.adobe.com/192.147.130.162] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```

where as I have used latest maven plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.0</version>
            </plugin>
```

, not sure why getting this error and how to resolve this

Comment: Looks like a network error: `Connection timed out: connect`..

Comment: Does this happen on your local machine or in the environment where your code is deployed? Maybe there are network restrictions that need to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Its not able to connect to repo.adobe.com:443. Check your setting.xml inside .m2 folder